# What library can I use to generate random mock data based on Open API spec inside a node application?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocking, openapi

I am looking for a library which would generate a mock data based on openapi spec (client side only). So the idea is not to have a separate local server, as it's done in [openapi-mock-express-middleware](https://github.com/aleksandryackovlev/openapi-mock-express-middleware#readme), but rather have data to be generated on fly inside front-end application.

Something like this I guess:

```
const spec = someOpenApiMockGenerator('path/to/spec-file.yaml');

const anEndPointData = spec.mock("someEndpointName"); 

console.log(anEndPointData);
// expected output is same as in expressjs middlware mentioned above.
```

[image]

Comment: There's [`openapi-sampler`](https://github.com/Redocly/openapi-sampler) but it generates static examples, not random ones. https://openapi.tools/#mock has a couple of Node.js projects in the list, but they seem to be standalone mock servers.